# RegExp negative lookahead to exclude string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a small script that avoids IEMobile but detects the MSIE version, in this case IE9. I'm trying to use negative lookahead in the RegExp to do this, but it's not working and I'm wondering if I'm using negative lookahead correctly? Any advice appreciated.

```
/^(MSIE 9.0(?!IEMobile))*$/i
```

The UA String of IE Mobile:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; SAMSUNG; SGH-i917)
```

Comment: Obligatory disclaimer: don't do browser detection, do feature detection!

Comment: It's not aimed at you in specific, but at someone who might find this question and think it's a good idea to do browser detection.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want, is the example user agent you have given accepted or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't need to anchor the regexp (so no `^` `$` symbols at start and end).

Second of all, your regexp looks for `IEMobile` right after the `MSIE 9.0`, when in your actual example they are farther apart.

Third of all, `.` means any character. If you want version 9.0, you should use `9\.0` in your regexp.

The correct regexp should be:

```
/MSIE 9\.0(?!.*IEMobile)/i // matches IE9, but not IEMobile
```